# How to list available npm global packages

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have a few global packages available in my computer. I want to list them all using npm command without going to to the global installation folder found using `npm root -g`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 npm list -g --depth=0
```

**-g** will look for the packages installed globally. If you need to check locally installed packages remove **-g**

**--depth=0** will avoid every dependency in the tree